# Wizz Priority trolley or handbag

Tags: wizz-air

I have an extra bag so I paid for Wizz Priority service but it is said: plus Trolley bag. But what if I have no wheels - just a handbag that fits into their dimension requirements?

Answer (score 4):

You should be good with your handbag. According to skyscanner, your bag does not have to wheels.

Here's the [link](https://www.skyscanner.co.il/tips-and-inspiration/wizz-air-cabin-baggage-rules) and quote:

> It can be a trolley or a backpack, as long as it fits the baggage sizer (including wheels and handles) – it’ll be allowed.